# Can the Visual Studio 2013 help viewer use the 2012 offline contents?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, offline-caching

Okay, so I read that Visual Studio 2013 makes use of the Visual Studio 2012 help content. Consequently I used [Visual Studio 2012/2013 Help Downloader](http://vshd2012.codeplex.com/) and now have a local cache of the help content.

Now I can import that into Visual Studio 2013 and 2012 **respectively**. But how can I make use of the already installed content from one VS version inside the other?

Is there a solution short of using hardlinks to save the disk space that would otherwise be wasted on the same contents?

*Side-note:* hardlinking saves approx. 1.3 GiB, but that's less than the expected half of the overall amount.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question in the title is yes.

VS 2013 can use same VS 2012 offline help contents.

If you use the offline help contents, VS will also not duplicate the actual physical file but instead reference to it.

Comment: Could you please detail how I get it to do that? Thanks.

Comment: you need to download the file from MSDN.

after you download, set help to local help viewer and then when you press F1 you can set your help contents to the file's path.

Comment: This is not helpful, I'm afraid. See, I am aware that I can apply the same catalogs to each HelpViewer version respectively. However, that means duplication of the data.  If I use the "Move content" option under "Manage content", I lose information that already exists and is version-specific. So what I would need is to reference an additional catalog.

Comment: I was able to get both VS 2012 & 2013 using the same offline content by deleting all the contents in the VS2013 local store path and then changing the VS 2012 local store path to the now empty directory of VS2013's store path. When you open VS 2013 back up it will then update with the contents that was in VS2012's help contents.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=34794 now contains and ISO for VS2012 and VS2013 documentation. Download the VS2013 ISO and it contains both. Then mount the ISO, and follow the html instructions on the disk.