# Does VS2012 Documentation work with VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I recently decided to try out VS2013 before making the jump from VS2010 and I found that I have to download the help files too. After searching online, it appears there is no ISO of the VS2013 documentation. I rather found documentation for [VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34794) and this [VS Help Downloader](http://vshd2012.codeplex.com/).

What I would like to know is:

> Does Visual Studio 2013 use the same documentation as Visual Studio 2012?

I need to be sure of this before I commence downloading the fairly large VS2012 Documentation ISO on my slow internet connection.

Comment: *cough* download resumers and off-time downloads *cough*

Comment: Possible Duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809357/can-the-visual-studio-2013-help-viewer-use-the-2012-offline-contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "yes", any VS2012 Help Viewer Content you have downloaded/installed will be used by the VS2013 Help Viewer. Additionally, when you use VS2013's Help Viewer to install help from online you may notice that only VS2012 help is (currently) available (there is no VS2013-specific Help Viewer content, yet.)

By default VS2013 uses MSDN Online, which is a change from prior VS versions (which relied on a local Help and/or MSDN installation.) This is why the VS2013 installation behaves differently and does not prompt for your Help preferences when installation finishes.

**If you just want to download for offline use** rather than constantly load content from online, from VS2013 navigate to Main Menu -> Help > Set Help Preference -> Launch in Help Viewer, this should prompt you to download the documentation if not already installed. You can also use the downloader built into the latest Help Viewer to download any content you're missing.

**If you want to download help once and store it for later** such as for multiple installations, limited/paid-for bandwidth, etc then you can consider using the [Visual Studio 2012/2013 Help Downloader](http://vshd2012.codeplex.com/) (an open-source project on CodePlex.) This allows you to download the content files and then import them into any installation of Help Viewer.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. As I said, I have a poor, intermittent internet connection which makes constant referral to MSDN online difficult at times, and hence my preference for the offline content however 'inadequate' it may be. I would also like to download the right one once and for all for future installations so using the built-in offline content downloader is not suitable for my needs.

Comment: I only meant to direct you to Help Viewer's content downloader, you don't actually require a third party solution if you only intended to get the correct help for VS2013 downloaded for offline use. I have, however, updated my answer to be more clear about current help availability, usage by VS and your two primary options for acquiring help content. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I found out independently that the two versions use the same documentation libraries. I'll go on to get the full docs for offline use.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used VS 2012. i m using VS 2013. after hectic search i found the following link for documentation from microsoft.com for VS 2012 and VS 2013. whatever your choice you can go for it

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34794

Comment: Congratulations! You found the link just one day after it was uploaded.